# Xpath test for ancestor attribute not equal string

Tags: xpath, attributes

I'm trying to test if an attribute on an ancestor of an element not equal a string.

Here is my XML...

```
<aaa att="xyz">
<bbb>
<ccc/>
</bbb>
</aaa>
<aaa att="mno">
<bbb>
<ccc/>
</bbb>
</aaa>
```

If I'm acting on element ccc, I'm trying to test that its grandparent aaa @att doesn't equal "xyz".

I currently have this...

```
ancestor::aaa[not(contains(@att, 'xyz'))]
```

Thanks!

Comment: An ancestor of *what element*? Do you mean an element that has at least one child element?

Comment: Sorry, had brackets around the element in question.  See my new line after the sample XML.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that by saying *an ancestor of an element* you're referring to an element with child elements, this XPath expression should do:

```
//*[*/ccc][@att != 'xyz']
```

It selects

1. all nodes
2. that have at least one `<ccc>` grandchild node
3. and that have an `att` attribute whose value is not `xyz`.

**Update:** Restricted test to grandparents of `<ccc>`.

**Update 2:** Adapted to your revised question:

```
//ccc[../parent::aaa/@att != 'xyz']
```

Selects

1. all `<ccc>` elements
2. that have a grandparent `<aaa>` with its attribute `att` set to a value that is not `xyz`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, I'm looking to test only on the aaa that is the grandparent of ccc.  From you explanation, this tests across all aaa nodes in the document.

Comment: @Jeff: This didn't get quite clear from your question; I've updated my response now.

Comment: @Jeff: I've added an alternative solution to demonstrate how to actually have the `<ccc>` element as the resulting node, as now stated in your question.