# How to scrape items only when author is not equal to Albert Einstein

Tags: python, scrapy

I wanted to find out how to extract the quotes and authors from the first page of http://quotes.toscrape.com/ ONLY if the author's name is not Albert Einstein.

```
<div class="quote">
    <span class="text">
        "some quote"
    </span
    <span>
        "by "
        <small class="author">Albert Einstein</small>
    </span>
    <span class="text">
        "some quote"
    </span
    <span>
        "by "
        <small class="author">J.K. Rowling</small>
    </span>
```

I've done some searching and the closest things I can find are these posts, but these only refers to not scraping if the attribute is not equal to something and not if the value is not equal to something.

1 [XPath for elements with attribute not equal or does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632699/xpath-for-elements-with-attribute-not-equal-or-does-not-exist)
2    [Xpath test for ancestor attribute not equal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144805/xpath-test-for-ancestor-attribute-not-equal-string)
3 [How to use "not" in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550981/how-to-use-not-in-xpath)
4 [Using not() in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418470/using-not-in-xpath)

I currently have...

```
class AllSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'working'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    divs = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']")
    for div in divs:
        l = ItemLoader(item=AllItems(), selector=div)
        l.add_xpath('title', ".//span[@class='text']/text()")
        l.add_xpath('name', ".//small[@class='author']/text()")
        yield l.load_item()

class AllItems(scrapy.Item):
    link = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    domain = scrapy.Field()
```

and have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to do anything and I get the same results as without the added code. Any help would be appreciated!!! The only other way I could think of doing this is post crawl when I can use pandas to filter the outputted .csv file, but if there's a way to do it through scrapy, I would love to learn it!

```
def parse(self, response):
    divs = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']")
    for div in divs:
        l = ItemLoader(item=AllItems(), selector=div)

        if l.add_xpath('name', ".//small[@class='author']/text()") != 'Albert Einstein':

            l.add_xpath('title', ".//span[@class='text']/text()")
            l.add_xpath('name', ".//small[@class='author']/text()")
            yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I would just do some post filtering on the output data. Not much point adding complex filtering logic in your scraper.

Comment: Not sure how the answer might look like, but if it's an easy solution, I would like to add that so I wouldn't have to take the extra step of post filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy and paste this:

```
l.add_xpath('name', ".//small[@class='author'][not(contains(., 'Albert Einstein'))]/text()")
```

Comment: Thanks for that! While it does work, when I output to csv, there's a blank cell for every time Albert Einstein was on.

Answer (score 0):

So playing around with it, I found the best way to do it would be either of these solutions. The first is if you have a single value to filter out while the 2nd is if you have a list of values you want to filter out. Thanks everyone who helped me out!!!

```
def parse(self, response):
    divs = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']")
    for div in divs:
        l = ItemLoader(item=AllItems(), selector=div)
        name = div.xpath(".//small[@class='author']/text()").get()
        if name != 'Albert Einstein':
            l.add_xpath('title', ".//span[@class='text']/text()")
            l.add_value('name', name)
            yield l.load_item()
```

or

```
def parse(self, response):
    authors_to_filter = ['Albert Einstein', 'Other Name']
    divs = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']")
    for div in divs:
        l = ItemLoader(item=AllItems(), selector=div)
        name = div.xpath(".//small[@class='author']/text()").get()
        if name not in authors_to_filter:
            l.add_value('name', name)
            yield l.load_item()
```